# Certification error - Tizen Hybrid app - Gear S2

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to run a Tyzen Hybrid app on my Gear  S2 althoug It's not working the comunication between the web and the Native projects. Log shows next error:

**amd_launch.c:_prepare_exec(256)> fail to set privileges - check your package's credential: -3**

I haven't had any problem to install my app on the Gear S2, also I can install both project separately on the device.

Also I've install the Hybrid app on an Emulator and works without any issue.

Does anyones know why the Native project is not getting the credentials when I'm building the package together with the web project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

Set --> Project properties > C/C++ Build > Tizen Settings > Architecture --> 'ARMv7-a'